# Solution book of John Kelley's , J.Munkres's

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I have so many difficult in solving problem in General Topology of John Kelley and Topology (second edition) of James R. Munkres. Does anyone know solution book of those? Just want to ask so many problem in there!

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: Of course i tried, and it's so hopeless!!

Comment: If only there was some sort of forum somewhere where someone could ask questions about particular mathematical problems they were having.  But I guess this is an idea as outlandish as [a fish with a transparent head](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2009/02/photogalleries/fish-transparent-head-barreleye-picture/)!

Comment: @ArthurFischer : D

Comment: @LeVanTu Sure, I just wanted to make sure that "the obvious" has already been tried.

Comment: Putting [munkres solution manual](http://www.google.com/search?q=munkres%20solution%20manual) into Google lead me to [this blog](http://dbfin.com/2010/11/2000-munkres-topology-solutions-chapter-1/).  
Maybe you can check it out, whether it is any good. (Or perhaps, if you stuck on some problem, you can post in on MSE.)

Comment: [This website](https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/) contains links to answers and solutions for exercises in the Munkres (2000) Topology, Second Edition.

Comment: [In this webpage](https://positron0802.wordpress.com/topology-munkres/) I uploaded solutions to Chapters 2 & 3 of Munkres' Topology just in case it might be helpful

Answer (score 5):

http://wenku.baidu.com/view/a4080a8da0116c175f0e48d7.html
There are some answers.good luck :)
Munkres

Answer (score 0):

This page has some solutions as well: http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/e03/3gt/3gt.html